# Encoding an binary image using a chain code

Tags: python, numpy, encoding

I am trying to solve this in python.

- Threshold is 230 - pixels above are set to foreground(1) and rest is set to background(0)
- 0-based (x,y) coordinate system in image is used
- Binary image is encoded using chain code

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[208, 208, 208, 202, 202, 202],
                   [231, 231, 231, 231, 193, 193],
                   [193, 193, 193, 167, 167, 167],
                   [167, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36],
                   [36, 40, 40, 217, 217, 217],
                   [25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25]])

# binary image is created
binary_image = np.where(matrix > 230, 1, 0)

# binary image is encoded
chain_code = []
for i in range(binary_image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(binary_image.shape[1]):
        if binary_image[i, j] == 1:
            if binary_image[i, j+1] == 1:
                chain_code.append(0)
            elif binary_image[i-1, j+1] == 1:
                chain_code.append(1)
            elif binary_image[i-1, j] == 1:
                chain_code.append(2)
            elif binary_image[i-1, j-1] == 1:
                chain_code.append(3)
            elif binary_image[i, j-1] == 1:
                chain_code.append(4)
            elif binary_image[i+1, j-1] == 1:
                chain_code.append(5)
            elif binary_image[i+1, j] == 1:
                chain_code.append(6)
            elif binary_image[i+1, j+1] == 1:
                chain_code.append(7)

print(chain_code) # output = [0, 0, 0, 4]
```

**The output should be: `(0,1) [0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4]`. What am I missing here?**

Comment: You get **`[0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 4]`** if you change all `elif` to `if`…